# find the angles of intersection when the line through the points (3,4) and (-5,0) intersects the line through (0,0) and (-5,0)

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the angle of intersection when the line through the points $(3,4)$ and $(-5,0)$ intersects the line through $(0,0)$ and $(-5,0)$.

Comment: please consult our [FAQ item on how to ask homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). In particular, please do not ask questions in the imperative, and please show your work.

Answer (score 1):

So we have points (3,4) and (-5,0) . Its equation of line would be `2y = x + 5`

The other is (0,0) and (-5,0) . Its equation would be `y = 0`

Thus it is the x axis.

So basically since we observe that (-5,0) is the intersection point the question is to calculate the slope of second line..

Thus we get tan( theta ) = 1/2

and get theta = tan inverse(1/2) to get the acute angle of intersection....